# Invalid path because of filename when hive load data local inpath

Tags: hadoop, hive

The file '/home/hadoop/_user_active_score_small' exactly exists. But when run `load data local` as below, get a SemanticException:

```
hive> load data local  inpath '/home/hadoop/_user_active_score_small' overwrite into table user_active_score_tmp ;
FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:24 Invalid path ''/home/hadoop/_user_active_score_small'': No files matching path file:/home/hadoop/_user_active_score_small
```

But, `cp /home/hadoop/_user_active_score_small /home/hadoop/user_active_score_small`, and then run `load data` again:

```
hive> load data local  inpath '/home/hadoop/user_active_score_small' overwrite into table user_active_score_tmp ;
Loading data to table user_bg_action.user_active_score_tmp
OK
Time taken: 0.368 seconds
```

The files' access type are the same, in the same directory:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 614 7月   5 13:49 _user_active_score_small
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 614 7月   5 11:48 user_active_score_small
```

I don't know how does this happen. Is file name which starts with '_' not allowed by hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files and directories that starts  with underscore `_` are considered hidden in MapReduce, that's probably the reason of the observed behavior.

If you look at `FileInputFormat` source code you can find this:

```
protected static final PathFilter hiddenFileFilter = new PathFilter(){
  public boolean accept(Path p){
    String name = p.getName(); 
    return !name.startsWith("_") && !name.startsWith("."); 
  }
};
```